# Basic Trouble getting jQuery AJAX success option to return value

Tags: jquery, ajax

My first time using json w/jquery and need to retrieve a json file. Even with this script I am unable to retrieve the json file. I never get to the line *alert("I'm in success function");*. Here is script I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- jQuery CDN -->
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script> 

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/readable/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Quiz App</title>
       </head>

  <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     alert("I'm in doc_ready");
 // jQuery AJAX request to read JSON formatted Test Questions & Answers from file
 $.ajax({
    url: "test.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
      alert("I'm in success function");
      alert(result);
   }
  });
 });
 </script>

<h3>Test for fetching JSON file from server</h3>
```

When I put breakpoint in at ajax call I print out first alert. But the one in success does not. I see from stepping thru it in firebug that it skips over the success option totally. I am at a loss for why. There are no exceptions thrown and I see from the http response body:

```
[{
    question: ["Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", "Who is the Vice-President of the United
 States?", "Who is Chancellor of Germany?", "Who is the Prime Minister of Canada?"],
    choices: [
      ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
      ["Barack Obama", "Bernie Sanders", "Nancy Pelosi", "Joe Biden"],
      ["Franz Ritz", "Angela Merkel", "Jan Schroeder", "John Stevens", "Karl Marx"],
      ["Wayne Gretsky", "Pierre Trudeau", "Mike Myers", "Justin Trudeau", "Justin Bieber"]
    ],
    correctAnswer: [0, 3, 1, 3]
  }]
```

Server is doing its job. Any input much appreciated.

Update: Now I get [object Object] on alert(result) since I put json file thru JSON Generator site.

When I put my json thru JSON Generator I get this which validates ok on JSLint:

```
[{
    "question": [
        "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
        "Who is the Vice-President of the United States?",
        "Who is Chancellor of Germany?",
        "Who is the Prime Minister of Canada?"
    ],
    "choices": [
        [
            "David Cameron",
            "Gordon Brown",
            "Winston Churchill",
            "Tony Blair"
        ],
        [
            "Barack Obama",
            "Bernie Sanders",
            "Nancy Pelosi",
            "Joe Biden"
        ],
        [
            "Franz Ritz",
            "Angela Merkel",
            "Jan Schroeder",
            "John Stevens",
            "Karl Marx"
        ],
        [
            "Wayne Gretsky",
            "Pierre Trudeau",
            "Mike Myers",
            "Justin Trudeau",
            "Justin Bieber"
        ]
    ],
    "correctAnswer": [
        0,
        3,
        1,
        3
    ]
}]
```

Update II: Here is the jQuery code once json format issue was corrected

```
var allQuestions = null;

 // jQuery AJAX request to read JSON formatted Test Questions & Answers from file
     $.ajax({
        url: "test.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
          allQuestions = result;
        }
      })
```

Truly "Write less, Do more" is correct.

Comment: It seems that your json is invalid....check it in this site: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: you haven't entered your data? in your ajax add data:{}, with your object.

Comment: Why did you duplicate the JSON in the question?

Comment: One was from response and one is from my json file. I thought you might need it. I know it is identical. I'm just confused as to why you say correct the json. From documentation I thought the json file is in correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not JSON. Attribute names have to be quoted. Use a `complete` handler which will be called no matter what the result of the call is to find out what is happening.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.json",
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function(jqXhr, status) {
        // Status will be "parsererror"
        alert("I'm in complete function: " + status);
    }
});
```

Your JSON should look like the following. Note the double quotes around `"question"`, `"choices"` and `"correctAnswer"`

```
[{
    "question": ["Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", "Who is the Vice-President of the United
 States?", "Who is Chancellor of Germany?", "Who is the Prime Minister of Canada?"],
    "choices": [
      ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
      ["Barack Obama", "Bernie Sanders", "Nancy Pelosi", "Joe Biden"],
      ["Franz Ritz", "Angela Merkel", "Jan Schroeder", "John Stevens", "Karl Marx"],
      ["Wayne Gretsky", "Pierre Trudeau", "Mike Myers", "Justin Trudeau", "Justin Bieber"]
    ],
    "correctAnswer": [0, 3, 1, 3]
}]
```

Comment: ok I get "I'm in complete function: parsererror". What do I do to assign contents of the response to a Global variable I will need for rest of script.? Is it jqXhr?

Comment: @alan Can't you just fix the JSON? You could use `var data = eval('(' +jqXhr.responseText + ')' )` but that would be a hack. Solve the root problem, don't patch it.

Comment: I'm sorry I dont understand you.  Why is my file not json? I copied it right from my script when it was embedded and worked fine. I am missing something. Is not my test.json file correct. I update question with contents of test.json. Thanks for patience.

Comment: kudos Juan once I got the json file straight it worked like a charm. So if the json file is formatted incorrectly it doesnt throw an exception you just have to validate your json? Within the script was different format then when I decided to break out json to seperate file?

Answer (score 0):

You actually had an invalid character in your JSON which was down to the question array having a breaking line in it.

Check out a working example of your code here, you just need the JSON to look like my data variable.

```
var data = [{
    question: ["Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", "Who is the Vice-President of the United States?", "Who is Chancellor of Germany?", "Who is the Prime Minister of Canada?"],
    choices: [
      ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
      ["Barack Obama", "Bernie Sanders", "Nancy Pelosi", "Joe Biden"],
      ["Franz Ritz", "Angela Merkel", "Jan Schroeder", "John Stevens", "Karl Marx"],
      ["Wayne Gretsky", "Pierre Trudeau", "Mike Myers", "Justin Trudeau", "Justin Bieber"]
    ],
    correctAnswer: [0, 3, 1, 3]
  }];

   $.ajax({
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
      alert("I'm in success function");
      alert(result);
   }
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wmxw9nnh/1/